# Multiple Ajax PUTs in Laravel 4 Giving Errors

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am updating my Model through a resource controller via jQuery Ajax Put. No problems at all the first time. This works fine:

```
        $(".addNest").click(function() {
            var nid = msg; //once the LI is added, we grab the return value which is the nest ID
            var name = $('.nestIn').val();

            if(name == '') {
                $("textarea").css("border", "1px solid red");
            }else {

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'PUT', // we update the default value
                    url: 'nests/' + nid, 

                    data: {
                        'name': name
                    },
                    success: function(msg) {
                        alert(msg)
                        window.location.replace('nests/' + nid ); //redirect to the show view
                    }
                });

            }

        });
```

Later in a separate code block, I try to call the PUT again like this:

```
$(".nestEdit").click(function() {

$(".nestEdit").hide();
var name = $('.nestName').data("name");
var nid = $('.nestName').data("id");

$(".nestName").html("<textarea class='updateNest'>"+ name +"</textarea> <span><a href='#' class='btn btn-mini nestUpdate'><i class='icon-plus'></i> Update</a></span>");

$(".nestUpdate").click(function() {

    var updatedName = $('.updateNest').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'PUT', // we update the default value
            url: 'nests/' + nid, 

            data: {
                'name': updatedName
            },
            success: function(msg) {
            alert(msg) // showing the error here
            location.reload( ); //refresh the show view
        }
    });
});
```

The 'updatedName' values and the 'nid' values are passing fine when I 'alert' them. When I view the return for the first PUT it comes back fine. However, when I view the return for the second PUT I get this:

```
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException","message":"","file":"\/Applications\/MAMP\/htdocs\/n4\/bootstrap\/compiled.php","line":8643}}
```

Anyone have some insights here? As you can tell, I am trying to do an inline edit. I have tried to wrap everything into a function but still not helping...

Comment: In my experience, NotFoundHttpException can be an unavailable method, an unavailable route or a rewriting rule problem. Console.log() all your generated URLs and test them manually, you're likely to find one that's giving you this same error.

Comment: is nid always the same? could be that one of those doesnt match a route.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel does not use PUT and DELETE natively since it is not supported in all browsers, you need to send a POST request with  '_method' set to either put or delete.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST', 
        url: 'nests/' + nid, 

        data: {
            'name': updatedName,
            '_method': update
        },
        success: function(msg) {
        alert(msg) // showing the error here
        location.reload( ); //refresh the show view
    }
```

EDIT: Ajax request do support PUT AND DELETE.

Comment: Surely that's only applicable to HTML? The AJAX module in jQuery can handle it, which is why it is there in the first place. "Natively" here should refer to performing an AJAX task without the use of JS...

Answer (score 0):

In your JavaScript code, for the inline editing, you are not making proper use of `$`.

If you click on `.nestEdit`, it's inner function should not be calling it by name, provided you have multiple objects of the same class on that page. This is why you get the error. Instead of sending the nest ID, it's sending an array object, which your Laravel Router will not pick up, because it is more than likely not defined.

Simply put, you should not be doing this:

```
$(".nestEdit").click(function() {
    $(".nestEdit").hide();
    ...
```

You should be making a call to `this`:

```
$(".nestEdit").click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    ...
```

So, for every `.nestEdit` within the inner function, you need to call for `this` instead.